# How I can create multiple request get/post page url

Tags: php

How I can create multiple get/post request in page URL?

Like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?goto=profile&id=11326
```

I already tried with this:

```
$doVariableprofile = isset($_GET['goto']) ? $_GET['goto'] : null;
if($doVariableprofile == 'profile') {
if(empty($_SESSION['logged'])) require_once('register.php');
}
```

how i can add more request? 
now i have http://www.example.com/?goto=profile

i trying do this http://www.example.com/?goto=profile&id=1

```
        $testt1 = isset($_GET['goto']) ? $_GET['goto']:null;
if($_GET['goto'] == 'profile?id=".$_GET['id']"'){


require_once('profile.php');

}
```

Doesn't work page when I add to profile?id="$_GET['id']"')

Comment: What do you mean by *add more request*?

Comment: @Chris i want do this http://www.example.com?goto=profile&id=here post id

Comment: Okay, can you not can access `id` with `$_GET['id']`?

Comment: @Chris how i can put one more $_GET to doVariableprofile?

Comment: Why do you want it specifically on that variable? Can you not assign it to another variable? If you must use the same, try using an array.

Comment: @Chris trying it by 3 days and i don't know how to achieve this url

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Is the problem *achieving that url* or assigning the `id` to a variable? Please modify your question above, and explain what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need `goto` and `id`, what have you tried and what isn't working. If you've tried something please post that code - even if you know it's wrong. I need to understand your issue.

Comment: @Chris i trying do this http://www.example.com/?goto=profile&id=1 i edit my post. sorry my bad english

Comment: @Chris yes is problems on put id on url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$goto = isset($_GET['goto']) ? $_GET['goto']:null;
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id']:0;

if($goto == 'profile' && $id != 0){
        require_once('profile.php');
}
```

you need to assign these values to variables, if you directly write $_GET['id'] in 
'if condition' and those values are not available then you may get

"Notice: Undefined index: " error.

Comment: You don't really need to assign them to variables. You do have to make sure the index exists though. `if (isset($_GET["goto"]) && $_GET["goto"]=='profile')` will do the same as `$goto = isset($_GET['goto']) ? $_GET['goto']:null; if($goto == 'profile') { ... }`

Comment: Use Lalit srikar's code. That one should work. I was just pointing out that storing them into variables is not necessary, but should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be done like this

```
$url = "profile?id=".$_GET['id'];

if($_GET['goto'] == $url){


require_once('profile.php');

}
```

another thing I understood this could be done like this

```
if(isset($_GET['goto']) && $_GET['goto']=="profile"){

   if(isset($_GET['id'] || $_GET['id']==''){

       header("Location: profile.php");

    }
}
```

Comment: its looks works but $_GET['id'] = null its work only on www.example.com/?goto=profile?id=

Comment: Look if there is no id means `profile&id=` then require_once('profile.php'); won't be called because if "is not set" .

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['id'])` this line means that is your id "is set" then call `require_once();`

Comment: What You are basically trying to do is that you want to check that if `goto` is set to `profile` and there is an `id` in url then it should be redirected to `profile.php`

Comment: hmm i don't know why but when i use www.example.com/profile.php?id=1 its work but www.example.com/?goto=profile?id= doesn't work

Comment: `www.example.com/?goto=profile?id=` this doesn't work and this would  probably not work. Because you see at the end `id=` means `id` is equal to null. Since there is no `id` it will not work.

Comment: Do you want your program to work on `www.example.com/?goto=profile?id=` this url?

Comment: Now check the second code. I edited it. Don't forget to accept the answer if it works

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Run-a-PHP-Script-With-Wamp-Server/ this link will help you out.

Comment: no you wrong understand me if(isset($_GET['goto']) && $_GET['goto']=="profile"){

   if(isset($_GET['id'] || $_GET['id']==''){

       require_once('profile.php');

    }
} this code don't work = my website don't work

Comment: User header() instead to require_once(); see my edited code above

Comment: It means you copypasted it correctly. Now changer `header();` to `require_once("profile.php");`